# ERB Interpolation data-attribute does not work

Tags: ruby, erb

I am having trouble interpolating Ruby in a data-attribute in my ERB template. I am trying to implement bootstrap modal on a `td` element of my page:

```
<td data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html= "true" data-content= "<ul><li>Paiement Adultes: #{tournament.name}</li></ul>"  data-trigger= "hover">
```

I am having trouble with the `data-content` attribute. I cant manage to display properly the `#{tournament.name}`. I have tried several methods with `<%= %>` and `#{}` but none of them seem to work.

How can I interpolate inside a `data-attribute` in ERB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to include the ERB tags `<%= %>`

*(I've omitted most code for readability)*

```
<td data-content="<ul><li>Paiement Adultes: <%= tournament.name %></li></ul>">
```

Comment: Everything inside of `<% %>` tags is ruby code. You would use `#{}` if you needed to print a variable with a string. For example: <%= "My name is #{username}" %>